# Problem with use of \newcommand "locally" vs on ShareLatex

Tags: texstudio, sharelatex, cv

I am trying to create a resume in Latex, and I'm using the [Clean CV template from ShareLatex.](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/clean-cv)

When I try to create the CV using the ShareLatex cloud editor, everything seems to work fine. However, when I try to download the tex source from the above URL and work with it locally, in TexStudio, I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}
Undefined control sequence. ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}
Missing control sequence inserted. ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}
Missing control sequence inserted. ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}
```

I am getting this issue on TexStudio 2.10.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.2. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it, add the `array` package in the preamble

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! But why does this work on the ShareLatex editor, then?

Comment: I do not know, I personally only use local compilers. Maybe sharelatex automatically loads some packages. A quick search did not give any results